# How to set background image for Android button but keep the gray button?

Tags: android, button, background

I need to set a background image for an android button (text button), but I want to keep the gray button.  When i use the setBackgroundResource() it has the image in place of the gray button.  How can I keep the gray button?

I tried using setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds, but the image only takes up part of the button, even when I have no text.

Notes: I will not have text while I display the image, but the button needs to be a TextButton because there will be text without images at times, and images with text at others.

Comment: What exactly do you want - an image in a button? The outline of the button?

Comment: I want the typical gray button, with an image inside of it. Taking up as much space in the button as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, after hours of thinking, I realized I could just create ImageButtons and TextButtons, and set the visibility (setvisibility(8)) to the buttons when I do not need them.  Setting the visibility to 8 for a view makes it be taken out of the layout, and completely disappear for the time being.